# ggplot2, x-axis not recognizing dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Trying to plot the following data frame (call it bob):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYrZ9.png)

Since the original date is in d/m/y, I use Finaldate and Value to graph.
Here is the code used to graph:

ggplot(Bob, aes(Finaldate, Value)) +geom_line() + geom_point(size = 3) +
labs(title = "TITLE",subtitle = "SUBTITLE", y = "Y", x = "X") +
theme_fivethirtyeight()+scale_y_continuous(name="name", labels = scales::comma)+theme(legend.title = element_blank())+scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE))

While I do get an output, it is not as a time series but rather the dates are not in order and the plot makes no sense. Attached a copy of the plot as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3yk4.png)

Not sure how to fix this problem, and have tried a couple of different things

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `Finaldate` to a date -- it is being treated as a character so all the dates are in "alphabetical" order. Try:

```r
Bob$finalDate <- as.Date(Bob$finalDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using
`+ scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d %m %Y")` (ggplot2)

https://r-graph-gallery.com/279-plotting-time-series-with-ggplot2.html